# How to list values of a group in a string in Microsoft Server Reporting Services (Visual Basic)?

Tags: reporting-services

### visual basic

[image]

#### SQL Result & Report

The PI Values (red) should be listet comma-separated for every group.
I have no idea. Please, could anybody help me?

[image]